# How to migrate stored procedures from existing database to Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Our existing project is being migrated to .NET Core, the issue is how to make the existing stored procedures (around 800) to Entity Framework Core.

Is creating model class for each stored procedure is needed? Is there a way to make it easier?

The existing project is a Winforms app which is being migrated to web in Angular.

Comment: I know this doesn’t answer your question, but if the stored procedures are effective and work well, there’s not an inherent reason why you would have to switch to EF. In fact, you might get performance decreases compared to regular SPs. Something to consider. More on topic to your question: each SP would not need a model, but each table likely would need a model.

Comment: To take them the last step, from Tables to EF-core model classes, then you can make an edmx  in classic EF and then just copy/paste the model classes to netcore. I have done that and it worked almost 100%.